# Command to find network interface for IP

Tags: windows, networking, ip, batch-file, ip-address

With `ipconfig` I can show the list of network adapters and their settings, e.g. the IP address.

I'm looking for a reverse command that displays the name of the network adapter for a given IP address.

I have tried filtering the output of `ipconfig` with a command like `ipconfig | find "192.168.2.4"` but then the adapter name is gone.

My output of `ipconfig` is (the tricky part seems that I have several addresses on one adapter here):

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.4
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.20
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.1
                                       192.168.2.1

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:
...
```

Comment: For a given local address, or to find out what interface routing uses to reach a particular remote address?

Comment: @BenVoigt: it's an address assigned to a network interface, so the result should be one adapter only. If it were about routing, the result could be many adapters (potentially with different metrics).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### How do I display the name of a network adapter for a given IP address?

This solution does **not** require any external commands (`pcre2grep`, `sed`, etc).

Use the following batch file (getname.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_adapter="
set "_ip="
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%g in ('ipconfig /all') do (
  set "_tmp=%%~g"
  if "!_tmp:adapter=!"=="!_tmp!" (
    if not "!_tmp:IPv4 Address=!"=="!_tmp!" (
      for %%i in (%%~h) do (
      if not "%%~i"=="" set "_ip=%%~i"
      )
    set "_ip=!_ip:(Preferred)=!"
    if "!_ip!"=="%1" (
        @echo !_adapter!
      )
    )
  ) else (
    set "_ip="
    set "_adapter=!_tmp:*adapter =!"
  )
)
endlocal
```

Usage:

```
getname ipaddress
```

Example:

```
F:\test>getname 192.168.42.78
Local Area Connection 2
F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [ipconfig](http://ss64.com/nt/ipconfig.html) - Configure IP (Internet Protocol configuration)

Comment: That's interesting David... almost programming! Your idea made me think, I'm posting my batch solution

Comment: @SalvoF It **is** programming. Batch has variables, `goto`, `for`, `if`, functions, macros ... what more do you need? ;)

Comment: I didn't know this until I wondered what has happened to my network config :-)

Comment: @ThomasWeller Do you know yet **how** it happened?

Comment: Not exactly. It certainly happened when I set up my 2 DSL lines. I have 2 DSL modems. They competed with DCHP, so I set up a fixed address. But that only used one DSL modem, ignoring the second. Some colleages made it work for 2 modems, potentially by setting 2 fixed addresses. Since that time, some of my batch files (and other stuff) is not working as expected any more. Hence the question.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thanks for the explanation, your help, and the green tick ;)

Answer (score 7):

You could use this PS one liner:

```
$addr='192.168.2.4'; get-wmiobject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |? {$_.ipaddress -contains $addr} |select Description |% {$_.Description}
```

To use it directly from command line:

```
powershell "$addr='192.168.2.4'; get-wmiobject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |? {$_.ipaddress -contains $addr} |select Description |% {$_.Description}"
```

or if you want to reuse it put it in a script and make the address a parameter

Edit: to get a name as it shows in Win/Ipconfig:

```
$addr='192.168.2.4'; 
$netconf = get-wmiobject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |? {$_.ipaddress -contains $addr};
$netconf |% {$_.GetRelated("win32_NetworkAdapter")} | select NetConnectionID |%{$_.NetConnectionID}
```

(the assignment to intermediary variables is only to make it a bit more readable)

Comment: This is cool, and it returns HW name. On my system `$powershell` is undefined though, I launch those commands with `powershell -c` from command prompt. On PS command line 1st one-liner runs as well.

Comment: @SalvoF oh that's just a typoo (part of my prompt)... It should be `powershell` I will correct it

Comment: This gives "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller" instead of "Local Area Connection" on my machine.

Comment: @ThomasWeller which in fact is a name of your network adapter as you per your question. But let me check, logical name should be obtainable as well

Comment: I tried `select Name|% {_.Name}` but that didn't work

Comment: It's on another table @wmz. PS rocks though: `powershell "$ip = '192.168.2.4';foreach($int in (gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapter)) {gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter """Index = $($int.index)""" | ? {$_.IPAddress -contains $ip} | % {$int.NetConnectionID} }"`

Comment: @ThomasWeller Check my edit. That was tougher than I thought! Fortunately PS supports `GetRelated` which eases `Associators of` methods a bit.

Comment: `GetRelated` matches common `Index` keys I believe. Very useful!

Comment: @SalvoF Yup I found it

Comment: @SΛLVΘ your comment is the solution I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

> I'm looking for a reverse command that displays the name of the
>   network adapter for a given IP address.

Based on everything I tried, this should work seems you say you need to get this information ONLY from the IP address which you already specify in your example.

**INTERACTIVE PROMPT FOR IP ADDRESS TO GET NETWORK CONNECTION NAME**

*(Use `WMIC` and some batch `FOR` loop `token` and `delim` parsing to get the network connection name for a specified IP address.)*

*(The result value will echo to a command window and a message box window. It's all batch script but dynamically builds some VBS script functions to simplify the process for anyone that needs.)*

```
@ECHO ON

:SetTempFiles
SET tmpIPaddr=%tmp%\~tmpipaddress.vbs
SET tmpNetConName1=%tmp%\~tmpNetConName1.txt
SET tmpNetConName2=%tmp%\~tmpNetConName2.txt
SET tmpBatFile=%tmp%\~tmpBatch.cmd
SET tmpVBNetCon=%tmp%\~tmpVBNetCon.vbs

IF EXIST "%tmpIPaddr%" DEL /F /Q "%tmpIPaddr%"
IF EXIST "%tmpNetConName1%" DEL /Q /F "%tmpNetConName1%"
IF EXIST "%tmpNetConName2%" DEL /Q /F "%tmpNetConName2%"
IF EXIST "%tmpBatFile%" DEL /Q /F "%tmpBatFile%"
IF EXIST "%tmpVBNetCon%" DEL /Q /F "%tmpVBNetCon%"

:InputBox
SET msgboxTitle=IP ADDRESS
SET msgboxLine1=Enter the IP address to get its Windows connection name
>"%tmpIPaddr%" ECHO wsh.echo inputbox("%msgboxLine1%","%msgboxTitle%")
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%N IN ('cscript //nologo "%tmpIPaddr%"') DO CALL :setvariables %%N
GOTO EOF

:setvariables
SET IPAddress=%~1
FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=3 DELIMS=," %%A IN (`"WMIC NICCONFIG GET IPADDRESS,MACADDRESS /FORMAT:CSV | FIND /I "%IPAddress%""`) DO (SET MACAddress=%%~A)
FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=3 DELIMS=," %%B IN (`"WMIC NIC GET MACADDRESS,NETCONNECTIONID /FORMAT:CSV | FIND /I "%MACAddress%""`) DO ECHO(%%~B>>"%tmpNetConName1%"

::: Parse Empty Lines
FINDSTR "." "%tmpNetConName1%">"%tmpNetConName2%"

::: Build Dynamic Batch with ECHO'd Network Connection Value
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%C IN (%tmpNetConName2%) DO ECHO ECHO %%~C>>"%tmpBatFile%"
IF NOT EXIST "%tmpBatFile%" GOTO :NullExit
START "" "%tmpBatFile%"

::: Build Dynamic VBS with Message Box Network Connection Value
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%C IN (%tmpNetConName2%) DO (SET vbNetconName=%%~C)
ECHO msgbox "%vbNetconName%",0,"%vbNetconName%">"%tmpVBNetCon%"
START /B "" "%tmpVBNetCon%"
EXIT /B

:NullExit
ECHO msgbox "Cannot find MAC Address, check to confirm IP Address was correct.",0,"Invalid IP">"%tmpVBNetCon%"
START /B "" "%tmpVBNetCon%"
EXIT /B
```

---

### ALL ONE-LINERS

**NATIVE WINDOWS ONLY WITH NETSH ALL INTERFACES (ALL IPv4 ADDRESSES)**

```
NETSH INT IP SHOW CONFIG | FINDSTR /R "Configuration for interface.* Address.*[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*"
```

[image]

**NATIVE WINDOWS ONLY WITH IPCONFIG ALL INTERFACES (ALL IPv4 ADDRESSES)**

```
IPCONFIG | FINDSTR /R "Ethernet* Address.*[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*"
```

[image]

---

### USING PCRE2GREP (per @SalvoF)

**SINGLE IP ADDRESS SPECIFIED**

```
netsh interface ipv4 show address | pcre2grep -B2 "192\.168\.2\.4" | FIND /V "DHCP"
```

**FIND ALL IP ADDRESSES**

```
netsh interface ip show config | pcre2grep -B2 ^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$ | FIND /V "DHCP" | FIND /V "Gate" | FIND /V "Metric" | FIND /V "Subnet"
```

**FIND ALL IP ADDRESSES (Cleaned Up Regex (per @SalvoF))**

```
netsh interface ip show config | pcre2grep "^[A-Z]|IP.*([0-9]{1,3}(\.|)){4}"
```

Please note that the `pcre2grep` I tried is per @SalvoF `[+1]` as he suggested but using the.... `FIND /V` to remove the line above containing `DHCP` seems to get the desired output as you described. I used `NETSH` rather than `IPCONFIG` as well.

Comment: This catches some extra information on my machines (as network masks, and such). My point was that in case you have multiple IP addresses, you cease having a "fixed" rule to get to interface name. Initial Q is: given an IP no. how do I find the interface it belongs to? I wasn't looking for all IP's.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs! BTW, I noticed that leading and trailing lines on my side were due to language issues. To circumvent those, what do you think about this? `netsh interface ip show config | pcre2grep "^[A-Z]|IP.*([0-9]{1,3}(\.|)){4}"` (I cleaned the regex a bit). I'm learning a lot around this place!

Comment: +1 Thanks for the suggestion. It still has too much output for my usage.

Answer (score 3):

To be more accurate, following OP's example, I'd use `sed`, which can be found under the `\usr\local\wbin` folder of [this zipped file](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/files/unxutils/current/UnxUtils.zip/download) (UnxUtils project).

```
ipconfig | sed -rn "/^[A-Z]/h;/192.168.2.4/{g;s/.* adapter (.*):/\1/p;}"
```

`-n` suppresses non matching lines; first pattern finds any line starting with capital letter, then `h` puts it away on hold space; second match is on wanted IP number: at this point, line holding interface name is recalled (`g`), extra leading text stripped (`s`), and printed (`p`).

Comment: `-B4` almost works, it just leaves me with the prefix "Ethernet adapter", which does not belong to the adapter name + 4 lines of unrelated output. But the message is clear: find a tool that does it :-)

Comment: Could you update your post to show unfiltered `ipconfig` output? (Obfuscate or change data for privacy)

Comment: Ok, added. It also seems to be tricky to handle adapters with multiple addresses.

Comment: That's brilliant @PJMahoney. What would be the output with multiple IP addresses though? I made an effort for a general solution by using `sed`; maybe your solution too can be tweaked to reach that goal.

Comment: The sed one works if I add another `| sed -rn "s/^.* adapter (.*):/\1/p"`

Comment: @ThomasWeller, I missed that additional text. Edited

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, here's another batch solution, it exploits delayed expansion of the `%ERRORLEVEL%` system variable:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%L in ('ipconfig') do (
    echo %%L | findstr /r "^[A-Z]" 1>NUL
    if !errorlevel! == 0 set "_int=%%L"
    echo %%L | findstr /c:%1 1>NUL
    if !errorlevel! == 0 (
       set "_int=!_int::=!"
       echo !_int:* adapter =!
       goto:eof
    )
)
```

It can be invoked this way: `find_int.cmd 192.168.1.100`

Comment: Hehe. That is a neat pure batch solution. Well done ;)

Comment: +1 The output is very close to what I need. Thanks

Comment: I edited the `sed` one-liner, leaving interface name as sole output. Of course, you can write a simple batch file for that too, passing the IP no. as argument (`%1`).

Comment: @ThomasWeller, tuned this one too. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the effort everyone. It seems there are several hurdles:

- the number of IP addresses assigned to an adapter
- the language of the OS

All the `-Bx` and Regex stuff seems to break easily, so I googled for something I could implement myself and came up with the following C# program, which takes the IP address as parameter (`IP2Adapter <IP>`):

```
using System;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace IP2Adapter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
            foreach (var adapter in adapters)
            {
                var ipProps = adapter.GetIPProperties();
                foreach (var ip in ipProps.UnicastAddresses)
                {
                    if ((adapter.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                        && (ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
                    {
                        if (ip.Address.ToString() == args[0])
                        Console.Out.WriteLine(adapter.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 Powershell, this can be achieved with the following:

```
Get-NetIPAddress -IPAddress '192.168.2.4' | %{$_.InterfaceAlias};
```

This will give a result such as `Wi-Fi`.

Where You can substitute `InterfaceAlias` for any other object property.

To get all properties, simply omit the pipes, and run: `Get-NetIPAddress -IPAddress '192.168.2.4'`.

Other network adapter related properties (such as Description) can usually be queried based on `InterfaceAlias` or `InterfaceIndex`, eg.:

```
Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceAlias Wi-Fi | %{$_.InterfaceDescription};
```

Which will give something like: `Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265`.

Read more on the docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netipaddress?view=win10-ps

Answer (score -2):

Open cmd as administrator

```
netsh interface show interface
```

Comment: This command does not involve the IP address in question, so it cannot work. And in the output of this command, the IP address is not even listed.